# iOS 7 Modal view transitions and the background/wallpaper

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

In iOS 7, I've noticed that during a flip modal view transition, rather than seeing a 'black' or dark background, I can now see wallpaper I have set for the brief moments during the transition, anyone know how I can go back to a black background?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind all, a restart of the device fixed it. Really strange bugs in iOS 7 at the moment. I had even killed the app several times, deleted it and re provisioned and only a reboot fixed this issue.